# Elegant way to look at a +/- range surounding a particular value in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I'm working with a large set of data in a spreadsheet using the openpyxl library.

I need to find certain temperature values and then look at other cells based on that temperature.

the problem is that my temperature fluctuates a bit in its measurements but I don't really care about this.

For example, if I want to look at the data when it's 25 degrees out, what I really want is the data ranging from about 24 - 26 degrees. And I need to do this for a number of temperatures.

I know how to do this in a rather messy iterative fashion like this:

```
for num in [5,10,15,20,25]:     
    if temp > num -1 and temp < num + 1:        
        #do things
```

but this just feels messy to me, is there any cleaner way to do it? Something like checking if temp is within a certain error of num?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have now is clear; Python allows you to chain the comparisons like this:

```
for num in [5,10,15,20,25]:     
    if num - 1 <= temp <= num + 1:        
        #do things
```

Another alternative is to check the absolute between the two:

```
for num in [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]:
    if abs(num - temp) <= 1
```

(If `temp` is an integer, you need to use `<=` instead of `<` for the expression to be different from simply `temp == num`.)

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to adapt what you have a little:

```
for num in range(5, 30, 5):
    if abs(temp - num) < 1:
        # do things
```

Answer (score 2):

How about a built in solution? You could just use the [**`isclose`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose) function located in [**`math`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html) (which is available as of `Python 3.5`):

```
from math import isclose

isclose(26, 25, abs_tol=1)
Out[409]: True

isclose(24, 25, abs_tol=1)
Out[410]: True

isclose(26.3, 25, abs_tol=1)
Out[411]: False
```

The `abs_tol` signalling the absolute tolerance (i.e difference) in order for two number to be considered close and `isclose` to return `True`.

Answer (score 0):

You can test for a value being in a range like this:

```
for num in [5,10,15,20,25]:     
    if num in range(24,27):
        ...
```

Note that this doesn't work if your incoming data is floats.
You can of course generate this range using some function that you give a center and a maximum distance from it:

```
def s_range(center, max_distance): # surrounding range
    return range(center-max_distance, center+max_distance)
...
if num in s_range(25, 1):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

For things like this I wrote a [generic range comparison function](https://bitbucket.org/charlie_x/python-httparchive/src/69f61eb29b7e48166c0266904eb872ab768e8d16/httparchive/views/utils.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#utils.py-18) which you could easily extend for use here. Although it might be overkill for this situation it makes a lot of sense if you have lots of similar checks with different values.

Use it like this:

```
range_comparison(operator.lt, [25, True], 24) # returns True
range_comparison(operator.lt, [25, True], 26) # returns None
```

You combine this with your own function for more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to use a built-in function in Python 2.x, there is also [numpy.isclose()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html)

```
from numpy import isclose as isclose
a = 100.0
b = 100.01

print isclose(a,b, atol=0.02)  # True
```

From the documentation:

> For finite values, isclose uses the following equation to test whether
>   two floating point values are equivalent.
>
> ```
> absolute(a - b) <= (atol + rtol * absolute(b))
> ```